# Multiple checkboxes in Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox

I'm finding this much trickier than I think it should be. I Have Django 1.4.5 and using the model prototypes and templates want to create the option to have multiple checkboxes. I'm keen to use the model, form and view methodology as I'd like later on to use a DB. Right now I'm simply having trouble finding how to display multiple check boxes that can allow multiple selections.

Models.py

```
GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male'),
    ('F', 'Female'),
    ('O', 'Other'),
)

class Gender(models.Model):
    MALE = 1
    FEMALE = 2
    OTHER = 3
    gender = models.CharField(('Gender'), max_length=512, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,blank=True)

class MyPreferences(models.Model):
    MyGenderPref = models.ManyToManyField(Gender, blank=True, null=True)
```

Forms.py

```
class MyPreferencesForm(forms.Form):
        MyGenderPref = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Views.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import forms
from TestForm.models import MyPreferences


def GoPreferences(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MyPreferencesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            commit=False means the form doesn't save at this time.
            commit defaults to True which means it normally saves.
            model_instance = form.save(commit=False)
            model_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
            model_instance.save()
            return redirect('victory')
    else:
        form = MyPreferencesForm()

    return render(request, "aboutme.html", {'form': form})
```

However when I try this, I get:

```
GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8080/myprefs
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
name 'MultipleChoiceField' is not defined
Exception Location: /home/brett/TestForm/TestForm/forms.py in MyPreferencesForm, line 17
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
```

What is the best way of doing this so I can later use a DB with minimum hassle. But in the meantime I cannot get this working.

Comment: Are you sure that your forms.py is using "forms.MultipleChoiceField()" and not just "MultipleChoiceField()"? Because that error message makes it look like the latter.

Comment: Ah Yes, I took it out, but the error message with form.XXX back in is: 'module' object has no attribute 'MultipleChoiceField'

Comment: What happens if you try "from django.forms import MultipleChoiceField" and then use "MyGenderPref = MultipleChoiceField(...)" in forms.py? If that works then Brenda's right and you're importing the wrong forms module.

Answer (score 0):

In the import section, you have

```
from django.forms import forms
```

maybe it should be

```
from django import forms
```